# cordova-plugin-media not firing success or fail events

Tags: javascript, cordova, ionic-framework, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins

My javascript skills are starting to improve (I think), but I'm having a very strange issue with cordova-plugin-media

I have added the plugin to cordova, but when I define the media object neither of the success or fail events are triggering.

I have put lots of console hints into my code:

```
$scope.testSound = function() {
    console.log("!!!!!!! DEFINING THE PATH");
    var src = "snd/emergency.wav";

    console.log("!!!!!!! DEFINING THE MEDIA OBJECT");
    var emergencySound = new Media(src, mediaSuccess, mediaError);  
    console.log("WE SHOULD BE FIRING THE SUCCESS OR FAIL METHODS NOW");

    function  mediaSuccess(){
        console.log("!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!Success");
        alert("Media loaded");
    }

    function mediaError(err){
        console.log("!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!FAIL");
        alert("Media failed to load");
    }
    console.log("!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!METHOD COMPLETE");

}

})
```

and the output is as follows:

```
I/chromium( 2978): [INFO:CONSOLE(173)] "!!!!!!! DEFINING THE PATH", source: file:///android_asset/www/plugins/cordova-plugin-console/www/console-via-logger.js (173)

I/chromium( 2978): [INFO:CONSOLE(173)] "!!!!!!! DEFINING THE MEDIA OBJECT", source: file:///android_asset/www/plugins/cordova-plugin-console/www/console-via-logger.js (173)

I/chromium( 2978): [INFO:CONSOLE(173)] "WE SHOULD BE FIRING THE SUCCESS OR FAILMETHODS NOW", source: file:///android_asset/www/plugins/cordova-plugin-console/www/console-via-logger.js (173)

I/chromium( 2978): [INFO:CONSOLE(173)] "!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!METHOD COMPLETE",source: file:///android_asset/www/plugins/cordova-plugin-console/www/console-via-logger.js (173)
```

I am expecting the fail method to fire, as I don't think my media file path is in the correct syntax, but not only is the fail not triggering, but there is no indication of an issue with the code (Android 4.4.2).

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a bug, I worked around it by not checking if there were any errors defining the media object.

Answer (score 0):

You should check the media status :

```
var media = new Media(src, mediaSuccess, [mediaError], [mediaStatus]);
```

> Media.MEDIA_NONE = 0;
>
> Media.MEDIA_STARTING = 1;
>
> Media.MEDIA_RUNNING =2;
>
> Media.MEDIA_PAUSED = 3;
>
> Media.MEDIA_STOPPED = 4;

And try this Media function : 
`media.getCurrentPosition(mediaSuccess, [mediaError]);`

Let me know.

Nico

Comment: the result is STATUS: -0.001

Comment: emergencySound.getCurrentPosition(statusSuccess, mediaError);
  
  function  statusSuccess(stats){
   console.log("STATUS: " + stats);
   }

Comment: Interesting.. I did a "mymedia.play()" and it did play.. so not sure why those events are not firing.